# Google Spreadsheet Script: Query(Importrange data not up dated when Cell Value is entered via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Scripting.

I have One Master Task List where in Status of all the Project assigned to other can be tracked.  File Link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WPi_YLm3XgfTRHYrLfK_8f2tgUQE-4SpHsjU0vR1bes/edit?usp=sharing

There are several other spreadsheets (Task) shared with persons to whom task are assigned. Relevant columns are pulled from Master File using Formula =Query(Importrange……. 
File Link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KBvM-P1PrLlr7z-i47_cEQF-qe9zATA4cygsggDRHxI/edit?usp=sharing

I have added script to this Task file whereby whenever Assignee updates on status or Remark in Column H & I, data is captured and MOVED to Master Sheet at the respective rows & Column.

Problem faces is that though Data gets properly recorded in the Master Task List File but same is not reflecting / does not get updated in Task File in-spite of the fact that  data is pulled from Master Task List file. Script reproduced below.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var firstDataRow = 2; // only take into account edits on or below this row
  var lastDataRow = ss.getLastRow(); // only take into account edits on or above this row
  var firstDataColumn = 8; // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column
  var lastDataColumn = 9; // only take into account edits on or to the left of this column
  var SourceCell = SourceSheet.getActiveCell(); //-

  if (SourceSheet.getName() != "Sheet1" ) return;
  if (SourceCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || SourceCell.getColumn() < firstDataColumn ||
      SourceCell.getRow() > lastDataRow || SourceCell.getColumn() > lastDataColumn) return;

  var SourceValue = SourceCell.getValue();
  var TargetCell = SourceSheet.getActiveCell();
  var SourceRow = SourceSheet.getActiveSelection().getRow();
  var SourceColumn = SourceSheet.getActiveSelection().getColumn();
  var InvoiceRange = SourceSheet.getRange("L"+SourceRow);
  var InvoiceCell = InvoiceRange.getValue();
  //Browser.msgBox(SourceValue, Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  var df = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1WPi_YLm3XgfTRHYrLfK_8f2tgUQE-4SpHsjU0vR1bes");
  Logger.log(df.getName());
  var ds = df.getSheetByName("Task");
  var lastRow = ds.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2;
  var DLastColumn = ds.getLastColumn();
  var DRange = ds.getRange(1,3,lastRow-startRow+1,1);  //-
  var numRows = DRange.getNumRows(); //-
  var MatchCellValues = DRange.getValues(); //-

  for (var i=0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
   var MatchCell = MatchCellValues[i][0]; 
    if (MatchCell == InvoiceCell) {
            // Found our match
     Browser.msgBox('Data Updated', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
     //Browser.msgBox(SourceValue, Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

      ds.getRange(i+1,SourceColumn).setValue(SourceValue);
      //ds.getRange(i+1,DLastColumn).setValue('*');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      break; // Done, exit loop
    }
 } 

   var SourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = SourceSheet.getRange('k1') 
   cell.setValue('*')
   TargetCell.clearContent(); 
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  //var cell1 = SourceSheet.getRange('A1') 
  //cell.setValue("=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WPi_YLm3XgfTRHYrLfK_8f2tgUQE-4SpHsjU0vR1bes/edit#gid=0","Task!A:J")},"SELECT* WHERE Col7 = 'JOHN' ")")
}
```

My second issue is that I get error message for line 53 in my script. I intend to use same in other script to rewrite same in case of accidental changes in Cell A1.

Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
Deven.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully got a correct QUERY formula to be put into the cell, but the QUERY will not update.  It won't even update after I refresh both sheets.  The QUERY in the Task sheet won't do anything unless I manually edit the Master Task sheet.  I'm guessing that it's either a bug, or it works that way by design.  Either way, you may need to try something different.

Use:

```
setFormula(formula)
```

Instead of:

```
setValue(value)
```

On line 53:

Because the formula has a combination of both single and double quotes, the formula must be constructed with a text formula.  Here is a function just for creating the formula as a string:

```
function createFormulaString() {
  var theFormula = '=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jzDLwag5tJvFbKZxZ486QfE8aeI56dsM9tpUxt-loHw/edit#gid=0';
  theFormula += '","Task!A:J")},"SELECT* WHERE Col7 = ';
  theFormula += "'JOHN'";
  theFormula += '")';
  Logger.log('theFormula: ' + theFormula);
};
```

You can call that function from your main function:

```
  var cell1 = SourceSheet.getRange('A1');

  var formulaString = createFormulaString();

  cell.setFormula(formulaString);
};
```

Comment: As regards to first part, could you suggest, as to what different approach can be taken. I have ran out of all ideas.